# Can we pass singleton class's object via intent?

Tags: android

Can I pass a singleton class's object from one activity to another activity using intent?  I am using singleton class as `imageclass img =  imageclass.getInstance();`, so i need the `img` instance for another activity, how can i pass an object instance in Android?

Thanks all

Comment: please clarify your question, perhaps by providing an example code.

Comment: Why you want to pass a Singleton class to another activity? It is already singleton and reachable anywhere in your project, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `imageclass` is.

Generally speaking, you don't really want to pass too much complicated between activities. Think of activities as being like Web pages of a Web app, and the Intents as being the URLs you use to launch Web pages. You do not typically pass arbitrary objects in a URL. Instead, you perhaps pass keys, identifiers, or other information in a URL, so the server can access the right arbitrary objects that are kept on the server.

Similarly, via `Intent` extras, you can pass simple data between activities, but you would not pass images, databases, business objects, or other complex materials that way. Instead, either keep those within a single activity, or maintain them in some central store (e.g., database, `Service`, custom `Application` subclass) and pass an identifier from activity to activity.

JonWillis' recommendation of using a content provider might work, but that is designed for fairly simple data structures, not your existing arbitrary objects.

Answer (score -1):

I advise you read up on content providers as the route to take to share objects, its a fundamental part of android programming. I would not be trying to pass an intent as a means to share data.

> A content provider makes a specific set of the application's data available to other applications

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Further info + tutorial : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: @plz give some example for me because i am fresher in android thanks

Comment: Sorry but i'm the same, i am fresh to it as well. But i have finished some background reading so i know the above is true, i have just yet not needed to use it.
Nonetheless i have included a tutorial/further info on them in my answer.

Comment: Content providers aren't really there "to share objects".